# How to use the same route for multiple routes in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

This is my routes component

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
  <Route path="page1" component={Page1}/>
  <Route path="page2" component={Page2}/>
  <Route path="page3" component={Page3}/>
  <Route path="articles/:id" component={DetailPage} />
</Route>
```

page1, page2, and page3 can be accessed from navigation bar, but DetailPage can be only accessed from each page. My path would be like: **/page1 => /articles/1**, and I want it to be **/page1 => /page1/articles/1**
is there any way that I can set current path in route component like this:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
  <Route path="page1" component={Page1}/>
  <Route path="page2" component={Page2}/>
  <Route path="page3" component={Page3}/>
  <Route path="currentPath/articles/:id" component={DetailPage} />
</Route>
```

or any better way?

EDIT
my index.js:

```
 ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('app')
 )
```

my routes.js:

```
export default {
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
      <Route path="page1" component={Page1}/>
      <Route path="page2" component={Page2}/>
      <Route path="page3" component={Page3}/>
      <Route path="currentPath/articles/:id" component={DetailPage} />
    </Route>
}
```

Indeed, most of my page components are very similar. each page receives json objects and iterates a list. When you click an item in a list, you will access to DetailPage component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way is to configure and parametrize your Pages as ":page" :

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
  <Route path=":page/" component={PageComponent}>
    <Route path="articles/:id/" component={DetailPage} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

The possible fallback of this is to validation of the "page" parameter, and you can add a check to "PageComponent" in order to define a validation set [page1, page2, page3, etc.], which redirects or anything you want to do with it

Comment: Agree, much more dynamic. Also for validation, you can easily leverage the [onEnter](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback) hook inside the `<Route path=":page/" component={PageComponent}>` so that you can react before entering the route, checking for instance that the parametrised page is correct, and redirecting to any other location otherwise.

Comment: @erdysson I am not sure how to do that . Do I have to create PageComponent and put all pages into it?

Comment: you can configure them via props, if they have very similar. If they are not, you can pass a component as a prop to the "PageComponent" and you can render it inside for example {this.props.childComponent}

Comment: I tried to do it, but I think I was doing wrong. What would PageComponent look like?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: I just added detail, so I thought you were talking about like creating another route with pages inside, and import it in routes.js

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic setup to achieve what you propose:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
  <Route path="page1" component={Page1}>
    <Route path="articles/:id" component={DetailPage} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="page2" component={Page2}>
    <Route path="articles/:id" component={DetailPage} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="page3" component={Page3}>
    <Route path="articles/:id" component={DetailPage} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Comment: I really don't want to do this because I have more than 3 components. I am sorry that I forgot to mention that. but thanks!

Comment: Just a note, thiis will anyways lead to mounting of those components again.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a JsFiddle that shows how to [build your example](https://jsfiddle.net/wbkob508/). It uses the [Navigation router](http://grahammendick.github.io/navigation/) instead of the React Router but I hope you're open to that. You can see that the Navigation router doesn't own your components so you can `ReactDOM.render` the right Page component using the page route parameter.  If you've got any questions about the code, please let me know.

```
var {StateNavigator} = Navigation;
var {RefreshLink} = NavigationReact;

var App = ({stateNavigator}) => (
  <div>
    <RefreshLink
      navigationData={{page: 'page1'}}
      stateNavigator={stateNavigator}>
      Page 1
    </RefreshLink>
    <RefreshLink
      navigationData={{page: 'page2'}}
      stateNavigator={stateNavigator}>
      Page 2
    </RefreshLink>
    <div id="page"></div>
  </div>
)

var Page1 = ({id, stateNavigator}) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
    <RefreshLink
      navigationData={{id: 1}}
      includeCurrentData={true}
      stateNavigator={stateNavigator}>
      Show Article
    </RefreshLink>
    {id ? <DetailPage id={id} /> : null}
  </div>
);

var Page2 = ({id, stateNavigator}) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
    <RefreshLink
      navigationData={{id: 1}}
      includeCurrentData={true}
      stateNavigator={stateNavigator}>
      Show Article
    </RefreshLink>
    {id ? <DetailPage id={id} /> : null}
  </div>
);

var DetailPage = ({id}) => <h2>Article {id}</h2> 

var stateNavigator = new StateNavigator([
  {key: 'example', route: '+/{page?}+/articles/{id}', defaultTypes: {id: 'number'}}
]);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App stateNavigator={stateNavigator} />,
  document.getElementById('container'));

var pages = {
  'page1' : Page1,
  'page2' : Page2,  
}
stateNavigator.states.example.navigated = (data) => {
  var Page = pages[data.page];
  if (Page) {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Page id={data.id} stateNavigator={stateNavigator} />,
      document.getElementById('page'));
  }
};

stateNavigator.start();
```